# Stacktrace on remote server points to local directory

Tags: asp.net, debugging, stack-trace

In order to troubleshoot an issue with a remote server, I copied over the non-compiled ASP.NET application to the server. The stacktrace indicates the code is located in C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects...

Where 'username' is my username. Why/how is the remote server loading or thinking it's loading code from my local workstation?

Comment: Are you positive the code that's running on the server is the non-compiled version? Make sure that there aren't any assemblies lingering in the `bin` folder from past deployments of the compiled application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems very much as if those paths are coming from a [PDB file which was compiled on your machine](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know).

Is it worth double checking (perhaps in the /bin directory) to make sure you haven't copied any DLL or PDB files over to the server with your application?

Comment: It was the pdb file - thank you!